# BMP Server on Cisco

Tags: cisco, bgp

I'm using router Cisco 2900 series with Cisco IOS 15.4(3) M3, and there is no BMP (BGP Monitoring Protocol) configuration. What should I do? What Cisco IOS version that provide BMP?

Comment: Which license do you have?

Comment: Cisco Feature Navigator (cisco.com/go/fn) It's never been 100%, but is usually good enough to find the necessary image.